# Python gRPC client working over a secure channel without SSL certificate

Tags: grpc-python

I saw below piece of code in a gRPC client that works:

```
ssl_metadata = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
channel = grpc.secure_channel('<my_grpc_server_path>:443', ssl_metadata)
```

I don't have the server code.

How is a secure channel created without a certificate and how will the server communicate over SSL?

Comment: it seems to be done internally via ssl_channel_credentials and secure_channel api